# Rails Factory Girl Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create associations with my factories using Factory Girl in a way so that associated objects share the correct data to match them together.

I'm running into scenarios where Object A is related to one instance of Object C, and Object B is related to another instance of Object C, when I'd like them to both be relating to the same instance of Object C.

Factory Girl - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md
Using newest version

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do in my project.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
        factory :neutral_position, class: FinancialAccounting::Update::Neutral::Position do
          created_at    { Time.now }
          updated_at    { Time.now }

          factory :valid_neutral_position do
            association :security, factory: :security

            factory :valid_neutral_position_with_production_record do
              association :position, factory: :position

              # This modifies the created production account record so the attributes match.
              FactoryGirl.modify do
                factory :position, class: FinancialAccounting::Position do
                  association :security, factory: :security
                end
              end
            end
          end

        end
      end
```

Notice I am trying to modify the associated position so that it will point to the same security generated in the :valid_neutral_position factory.  This code currently creates two separate securities, so the neutral position is associated with one security, while the position factory is associated with a different security.

How can I achieve this?  I see this issue all throughout my application so figuring this out would dramatically improve my app testing suite and keep my code DRY.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier to sort this out in your tests/specs rather than factory definitions.

First create a security and assign it to a variable.

Then, when creating an object that you want to depend on that security pass the variable into the factory constructor.

Although your example is a little complex it may look like this:

```
specific_security = FactoryGirl.create(:security)
valid_natural_position = FactoryGirl.create(:valid_natural_position, security: specific_security)
position = FactoryGirl.create(:position, security: specific_security)
```

In this way you can ensure the object relationships are set up in your tests the way you need them. It has the added benefit of reducing the number of objects created as the two secondary factories will no longer auto create security objects.

Comment: That is what we too are doing, but then why is the Factory associations made?

Answer (score 1):

I actually went with a different method.  It's contained to the factories, which leads to cleaner tests.  However, I do see the downside of having to generate more objects when you might not necessarily want to.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :neutral_position, class: FinancialAccounting::Update::Neutral::Position do
    created_at    { Time.now }
    updated_at    { Time.now }

    factory :valid_neutral_position do
      has_production_position
    end

    trait :has_production_position do
      association :position, factory: :position
      security { position.security }
    end

  end
end
```